# sql join using the below

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know I am doing something wrong, but both tables appear as joins.

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    users ON users.id = (SELECT id
                         FROM table2 
                         WHERE type = 'user') t t.id
```

If I had to a join on the other hand site, its feasible and doable, but for this type, I am not sure I can assign the value like this or not

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Comment: That `LEFT JOIN` seems very wrong. Having a subquery in your `ON` clause certainly seems wrong, and the `ON` clause doesn't even reference `table1`. Also that subquery has an `INNER JOIN` with no table, let along an `ON` defined.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: i removed the inner join which is invalid, but that is how it is

Comment: i know my join is wrong, but i am trying to do a join correctly, it does not have any linking with table 1, u see i am joining the user table

Comment: No, that's not a scalar result.

Comment: How are you supposed to join `table1`  to `users` if they don't have relationship???  Join on what???

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I totally understand the query, but if you are looking to use a join table to connect a many to many relationship try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 on t1.id = t2.id AND t2.type = 'user'
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u on u.id = t2.id
```